# Password maker in C#

Tags: c#, beginner, security

I need to generate semi-complex throw-able passwords (just one use) in my application. I want it to be:

- at least 8 characters long;
- contains at least 1 digit, 1 [a-z] char, 1 [A-Z] char;

I generate a few passwords a day, and I don't mind about speed. I'm more looking for suggestions about code being maintainable (or not) and possible huge security flaws. Here's the code:

```
public static string GenerateSimplePassword(int length = 8)
{
    length = Math.Max(length, 8);

    var allowedLower = new[] { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z' };
    var allowedDigits = new[] { '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9' };
    var allowedUpper = allowedLower.Select(x => char.ToUpper(x)).ToArray();

    var r = new Random();
    var generatedCode = "";
    generatedCode += allowedLower[r.Next(0, allowedLower.Length)];

    generatedCode += allowedDigits[r.Next(0, allowedDigits.Length)];

    generatedCode += allowedUpper[r.Next(0, allowedUpper.Length)];

    var arrays = new[] { allowedLower, allowedUpper, allowedDigits };
    for (var i = 0; i < length - 3; i++)
    {
        var array = arrays[r.Next(0, arrays.Length)];
        generatedCode += array[r.Next(0, array.Length)];
    }

    return String.Join("", generatedCode.OrderBy(x => r.Next()));
}
```

Comment: Are these password composition rules yours, or an external requirement? Consider that the number of possible 8-character passwords composed from "0 or more characters from each list" is actually smaller than the number of possible 8-character passwords composed from "at least 1 character from each list".

Comment: How are these passwords used? Can several people share the same random password? Does a password need to expire the next day?

Comment: @benj2240 external requirement. I guess it avoid password with only lowercase char for example.

Comment: @dfhwze it's for OTP. No expiration here.

Comment: No special characters such as `@, !, #, $` ?

Comment: @pacmaninbw users are quite low tech, so yes, we avoid special char in this generator

Comment: @benj2240 did you confuse "smaller" with "larger" in your above comment? It doesn't make sense to me in its current form.

Comment: What version of .NET are you using?

Answer (score 9):

**Fully Refactored Code:** [see this Gist](https://gist.github.com/Kittoes0124/d3b78a5c94a2bb0801ccbc50f51596d7)

**Example Usage:**

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    var generator = new PasswordGenerator(new PasswordGeneratorOptions {
        MinimumNumberOfLowerCaseCharacters = 1,
        MinimumNumberOfNumericCharacters = 1,
        MinimumNumberOfUpperCaseCharacters = 1,
        OutputLength = 8,
        SpecialCharacters = new char[0] { },
    });

    Console.WriteLine(generator.Next());
}
```

**Review Comments:**

First off, using `Random` as a source of entropy probably isn't the best idea since it is *possible* (however unlikely) that an attacker could gain the underlying seed; with it they would trivially be able to deduce all of the outputs used to generate our passwords. Let's implement a generator that uses a static instance of the `RNGCryptoServiceProvider` class instead:

```
// makes it easier to replace the implementation I demonstrate with something better
public interface ISecureRandom
{
    uint Next(uint x, uint y);
}

// a possible implementation of a secure RNG, not exhaustively tested...
public sealed class SecureRandom : ISecureRandom
{
    private static readonly RandomNumberGenerator DefaultRandomNumberGenerator = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();

    public static SecureRandom DefaultInstance => new SecureRandom(DefaultRandomNumberGenerator);

    private readonly RandomNumberGenerator m_randomNumberGenerator;

    public SecureRandom(RandomNumberGenerator randomNumberGenerator) {
        if (null == randomNumberGenerator) {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(paramName: nameof(randomNumberGenerator));
        }

        m_randomNumberGenerator = randomNumberGenerator;
    }

    public byte[] GetBytes(byte[] buffer) {
        m_randomNumberGenerator.GetBytes(buffer);

        return buffer;
    }
    public byte[] GetBytes(int count) => GetBytes(new byte[count]);
    public uint Next() => BitConverter.ToUInt32(GetBytes(sizeof(uint)), 0);
    public uint Next(uint x, uint y) {
        if (x > y) {
            var z = x;

            x = y;
            y = z;
        }

        var range = (y - x);

        if (range == 0) {
            return x;
        }
        else if (range == uint.MaxValue) {
            return Next();
        }
        else {
            return (Next(exclusiveHigh: range) + x);
        }
    }

    private uint Next(uint exclusiveHigh) {
        var range = (uint.MaxValue - (((uint.MaxValue % exclusiveHigh) + 1) % exclusiveHigh));
        var result = 0U;

        do {
            result = Next();
        } while (result > range);

        return (result % exclusiveHigh);
    }
}
```

Regarding maintainability, we could start by creating a proper class to encapsulate all of our settings:

```
public sealed class PasswordGeneratorOptions
{
    private static readonly char[] DefaultSpecialChars = new[] { '!', '@', '#', '$', '%', '^', '&', '*', '(', ')', '-', '=', '`', '~', '_', '+', ',', '.', '\'', '"', ';', ':', '?', '|', '/', '\\', '[', ']', '{', '}', '<', '>' };

    public int MinimumNumberOfNumericCharacters { get; set; }
    public int MinimumNumberOfLowerCaseCharacters { get; set; }
    public int MinimumNumberOfSpecialCharacters { get; set; }
    public int MinimumNumberOfUpperCaseCharacters { get; set; }
    public int OutputLength { get; set; }
    public ISecureRandom RandomNumberGenerator { get; set; }
    public IReadOnlyList<char> SpecialCharacters { get; set; }

    public PasswordGeneratorOptions() {
        MinimumNumberOfLowerCaseCharacters = 0;
        MinimumNumberOfNumericCharacters = 0;
        MinimumNumberOfSpecialCharacters = 0;
        MinimumNumberOfUpperCaseCharacters = 0;
        RandomNumberGenerator = SecureRandom.DefaultInstance;
        SpecialCharacters = DefaultSpecialChars;
    }
}
```

Then we can declare a `PasswordGenerator` class that consumes our options:

```
public sealed class PasswordGenerator
{
    private readonly PasswordGeneratorOptions m_options;

    public PasswordGenerator(PasswordGeneratorOptions options) {
        if (options.OutputLength < (options.MinimumNumberOfLowerCaseCharacters + options.MinimumNumberOfNumericCharacters + options.MinimumNumberOfSpecialCharacters + options.MinimumNumberOfUpperCaseCharacters)) {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(message: "output length must be greater than or equal to the sum of all MinimumNumber* properties", actualValue: options.OutputLength, paramName: nameof(options.OutputLength));
        }

        m_options = options;
    }
}
```

Now we can start thinking about implementation details, I personally like the idea of breaking things up into various categories so that we can provide more complex configuration options later. Let's try classifying your characters into `lower-case`, `upper-case`, `number`, and `special`. The ASCII encoding has largely taken care of all of this for us "for free" since three of these four classes have contiguous regions in the specification; we can write a simple generator for each like so:

```
var randomNumberGenerator = new SecureRandom();

Func<char> GetAsciiLetterLowerCase = () => ((char)randomNumberGenerator.Next(97, 123));
Func<char> GetAsciiLetterUpperCase = () => ((char)randomNumberGenerator.Next(65, 91));
Func<char> GetAsciiNumber = () => ((char)randomNumberGenerator.Next(48, 58));
```

Special characters aren't as easy so we'll resort to using a table of values:

```
var specialCharacters = new char[] { '!', '@', '#', };

Func<char> GetAsciiSpecial = () => specialCharacters[randomNumberGenerator.Next(0U, ((uint)specialCharacters.Count))];
```

The only remaining thing left to do is implement the generator function. This can be accomplished by more or less following the same strategy you already have in place. I chose to implement [Fisher–Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) instead of using `LINQ` for the final randomization step:

```
public string Next() {
    var index = 0;
    var length = m_options.OutputLength;
    var randomNumberGenerator = m_options.RandomNumberGenerator;
    var result = new char[length];
    var useSpecial = (0 < m_options.SpecialCharacters.Count);

    for (var i = 0; (i < m_options.MinimumNumberOfLowerCaseCharacters); i++) {
        result[index++] = m_getAsciiLetterLowerCase();
    }

    for (var i = 0; (i < m_options.MinimumNumberOfNumericCharacters); i++) {
        result[index++] = m_getAsciiNumeric();
    }

    for (var i = 0; (i < m_options.MinimumNumberOfSpecialCharacters); i++) {
        result[index++] = m_getAsciiSpecial();
    }

    for (var i = 0; (i < m_options.MinimumNumberOfUpperCaseCharacters); i++) {
        result[index++] = m_getAsciiLetterUpperCase();
    }

    for (var i = index; (i < length); i++) {
        char c;

        switch (randomNumberGenerator.Next(0U, (useSpecial ? 4U : 3U))) {
            case 3U:
                c = m_getAsciiSpecial();
                break;
            case 2U:
                c = m_getAsciiNumeric();
                break;
            case 1U:
                c = m_getAsciiLetterLowerCase();
                break;
            case 0U:
                c = m_getAsciiLetterUpperCase();
                break;
            default:
                throw new InvalidOperationException();
        }

        result[i] = c;
    }

    FisherYatesShuffle(randomNumberGenerator, result);

    return new string(result);
}

private static void SwapRandom<T>(ISecureRandom randomNumberGenerator, IList<T> list, uint indexLowerBound, uint indexUpperBound) {
    var randomIndex = randomNumberGenerator.Next(indexLowerBound, indexUpperBound);
    var tempValue = list[(int)randomIndex];

    list[(int)randomIndex] = list[(int)indexUpperBound];
    list[(int)indexUpperBound] = tempValue;
}
private static void FisherYatesShuffle<T>(ISecureRandom randomNumberGenerator, IList<T> list) {
    var length = list.Count;
    var offset = 0U;

    while (offset < length) {
        SwapRandom(randomNumberGenerator, list, 0U, offset++);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there really no predefined `SecureRandom` class in .NET? It sounds really strange that everyone would have to write this class by themselves.

Comment: This code looks really bloated, compared to the original code. Generating a password using a given simple and fixed scheme should take no more than 30 lines of code.

Comment: @RolandIllig Sadly, there really isn't anything in the standard lib; I'd have used it. One concedes that the code is bloated but figured that having parameters is more "maintainable" in the long run; for example, one might be dealing with many clients that all have different configurations (or, heaven forbid, a client that changes their requirements over time).

Comment: Very, very firm uptick for using `RNGCryptoServiceProvider`.  While yes, it's very unlikely that an attacker will get the seed, it's always best to use cryptographically secure system when working with any part of authentication, especially CSPRNGs over DPRNGs.

Comment: The default `Random` class uses the system time as the seed. More specifically, the [`Environment.TickCount`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.tickcount?view=netframework-4.8). This makes it REALLY EASY to guess the seed. There are so few options, you can just check them all! So, yes, in a serious implementation, using the `RNGCryptoServiceProvider` is a must. For homework, of course, the default `Random` class will be just fine.

Comment: An extension method would be *far* simpler than using a completely separate class for generating integers, which is only required for the shuffle anyway. I also recommend against injecting instances of random number generators. A *very* common mistake in using RNGs is creating multiple instances rather than reusing the same one. Having a single, static final instance will discourage this mistake and give you a place to leave a comment reminding everyone to not to new up their own instance.

Comment: Varying the minimum number of each type of character is also not a requirement and is an additional complication that is not needed here.

Comment: @jpmc26 While simpler, the static extension method wouldn't have been able to implement the ISecureRandom interface; a key feature that keeps the PasswordGenerator completely ignorant of how the numbers are generated (notice that the parameterless constructor now falls back to using a statically defined readonly rng). Varying the minimum characters might not be a requirement but it makes the code more generally useful. The OP actually has a decent approach and it seemed like a good idea to "amplify" it by making different variables available to a consumer.

Comment: @Kittoes0124 The interface is a bad idea. Injecting RNGs leads to the mistake of creating many instances. `PasswordGenerator` would not contain any more direct knowledge of the implementation RNG either way. And in fact, you could still inject an instance of `RNGCryptoServiceProvider` just as easily, if you absolutely insisted. There's no useful decoupling accomplished by it.

Comment: @Kittoes0124 Regarding "amplifying," that is often how we get ourselves into trouble overcomplicating our problems. I would rather discourage this tendency for people asking for review than jump into it ourselves.

Comment: @jpmc26 What you're saying about "many instances" is just nonsense though, it isn't up to us to decide how another developer uses their own tools; if they want to pass in a different RNG to each instance then so be it! The decoupling might be generally useless in most production scenarios but it ends up being immensely valuable in other contexts, such as unit testing. I understand where you're coming from regarding complication but it is hard to take you seriously when you're essentially complaining that arbitrary magic constants were converted into proper variables.

Comment: @Kittoes0124 "...if they want to pass in a different RNG to each instance then so be it!" No. That will silently prevent the very randomness we seek to enforce. Code should be written to reduce risks. As for unit testing, no. Your unit tests should not try to replace an RNG directly. Ever. You should not be writing tests that assert on specific outputs when randomness is a core requirement of the method. *Maybe* you might want to fake out the thing that uses the RNG, but not the RNG itself. It's typically better to convert randomly generated items into a input, though, and avoid the coupling.

Comment: @jpmc26 "That will silently prevent the very randomness we seek to enforce." What in the world are you talking about?! An RNG class that allows multiple instances isn't inherently broken in any way; some implementations might be broken but that doesn't mean we're forced to code around them. Requiring the `ISecureRandom` interface is a rather strong contract since no wild class is going to inherently have it; and yes, I do want to fake out the thing that uses the RNG... one huge reason for the interface is to send `PasswordGenerator` predictable inputs.

Comment: I'm talking about the kind of mistake the OP made. They created multiple instances of an RNG, which actually *reduces* the randomness. It may not be clear to some developers that the instance needs to be shared. "one huge reason for the interface is to send `PasswordGenerator` predictable inputs." This doesn't make sense to me because it's required that `PasswordGenerator`'s output be random. As a result, sending it predictable inputs breaks its interface. I don't consider such a unit test to be meaningful.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96157/discussion-between-kittoes0124-and-jpmc26).

Answer (score 8):

When calling your method like this:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(GenerateSimplePassword());
  }
```

I get this result:

```
    88yuQg7H
    u5UqU36o
    u5UqU36o
    u5UqU36o
    u5UqU36o
    u5UqU36o
    u5UqU36o
    u5UqU36o
    u5UqU36o
    u5UqU36o
```

which is not so random.

The reason is the `Random` object being instantiated each time the method is called. Instead you must move the `Random` object outside the method as a `static` one time initialized field.

---

You could make the valid chars as a static field string:

```
const string chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
static int DigitStart = chars.IndexOf('0');
static int UpperStart = chars.IndexOf('A');
```

---

Instead of concatenate strings throughout the process it would be better to use:

`char[] password = new char[length]`

it will improve both performance and readability:

```
password[0] = chars[random.Next(0, DigitStart)];
```

---

All in all my suggestion would be something like:

```
public static class PasswordGenerator
{

  static readonly Random random = new Random();
  const string chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
  static int DigitStart = chars.IndexOf('0');
  static int UpperStart = chars.IndexOf('A');

  public static string GenerateSimplePassword(int length = 8)
  {
    length = Math.Max(length, 8);

    char[] password = new char[length];
    password[0] = chars[random.Next(0, DigitStart)];
    password[1] = chars[random.Next(DigitStart, UpperStart)];
    password[2] = chars[random.Next(UpperStart, chars.Length)];

    for (int i = 3; i < length; i++)
    {
      password[i] = chars[random.Next(0, chars.Length)];
    }

    return new string(password.OrderBy(_ => random.Next()).ToArray());
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The string is shuffled with `generatedCode.OrderBy(x => r.Next()`, how the hacker could find out anything? But it gives a hint about bad code readability. I don't see how the simpler solution would assure that I get any of the 3 different char class. Does it?

Comment: @ThomasAyoub: Sorry, I missed the last line of code. But why do you want at least one of each?

Comment: Which version of .NET you use? According to @Eric Lippert this problem with Random is resolved in later versions.

Comment: @dfhwze: I use 4.8. I've see he commented that somewhere, but can't remember where. Apparently it is not solved yet. Maybe in core? [his blog](https://ericlippert.com/2019/01/31/fixing-random-part-1/): _"Fortunately, I have just learned from an attentive reader that this problem has been fixed in some versions of the CLR; exactly which I am not sure..."_?

Comment: @Eric Lippert Eric's answer here talks about it: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/223593/deck-of-cards-with-shuffle-and-sort-functionality/223604#223604

Comment: @dfhwze: Yes - that's also my reference

Answer (score 4):

## Most of your variables should be `static readonly`

There is no reason to new up a brand new copy of the arrays of characters each time you run this function. Instead:

```
public static readonly ReadOnlyCollection<char> AllowedLower = ReadOnlyCollection<char>("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");
public static readonly ReadOnlyCollection<char> AllowedUpper = new ReadOnlyCollection<char>(AllowedLower.Select(x => char.ToUpper(x)));
public static readonly ReadOnlyCollection<char> AllowedDigits = new ReadOnlyCollection<char>("0123456789");
```

Note that for static, read only lists of things, we use [`ReadOnlyCollection`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.readonlycollection-1) to prevent modification at run time. There are some alternative implementations of read only collections in .NET depending on your version; any of them is also fine.

While we're at it, we can greatly improve readability by passing just one string, which implements `IEnumerable<char>`.

## Randomness problems

You have two incredibly major problems with randomness:

1. The first is that you create a new instance of `Random` each time you invoke the function. That is ***wrong***. You *must reuse* the same instance of a random number generator when generating many random numbers to ensure that it is sufficiently random.
2. You're using `Random` which doesn't meet the level of randomness required for security algorithms. You need this level of randomness for generating passwords. You should use [`RNGCryptoServiceProvider`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rngcryptoserviceprovider).

```
public static readonly RNGCryptoServiceProvider SecureRNG = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
```

## Selecting random characters

Once the minimum requirements for each group of characters is met, you use a two stage random selection to choose the remaining characters. Because each group is not of the same length, this actually reduces the randomness. Any single digit has a higher probability of being selected than any single letter.

To resolve this, combine all of the characters into a single collection:

```
public static readonly ReadOnlyCollection<char> PasswordAlphabet = new ReadOnlyCollection<char>(AllowedLower.Concat(AllowedUpper).Concat(AllowedDigits));
```

And then select from that:

```
generatedPassword += PasswordAlphabet[randomIndex]
```

## Use a more standard shuffle algorithm

Since we can't use `Random` and `RNGCryptoServiceProvider` doesn't provide a `Next()`, using `OrderBy` to shuffle the password becomes more difficult. We need to ensure that our shuffling doesn't have biases in the order, and we need to do so without using `double`s.

Luckily, this is a [solved problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1262619/1394393). We'll use that solution.

## Selecting a random character from the lists

You may have noticed that we skipped over how to generate `randomIndex` in the code above that selects a random character. That is because `RNGCryptoServiceProvider` does not readily implement a means of doing so. We'll need to implement the ability to randomly select from a range of values.

The typical way of generating a random integer in a range is to [first calculate a random `double` and then multiply it by the range's length](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16907577/1394393). We can do this with a couple extension methods that we'll implement later.

## Prefer LINQ to loops

We don't need a `for` loop here. We can use LINQ:

```
generatedPassword += String.Join(
    "",
    Enumerable.Range(0, length - 3).Select(i => /* Get a random character */)
);
```

## Don't silently replace inputs

While it's good that you restricted your method to require at least an 8 character password, it's *not* good to return something that the caller did not ask for. Instead of replacing the length, throw an error:

```
if (length < 8)
{
    throw new ArgumentException(paramName: nameof(length), message: "must be at least 8");
}
```

Higher levels of code may choose to replace user input, but that kind of logic belongs there in the caller, not here in the depths of the implementation.

## What about dependency injection?

Should any of this be written in the dependency injection style?

Firstly, I would say that the secure RNG instance should **not** be injected. A random number generator is one of the few elements of code where doing so is a bad idea. The reason is the very mistake you made in your code: you need a single, permanent instance of the RNG reused over and over. The secure version is [notably thread safe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10525521/1394393), so it's fine to have just a single instance. In fact, I would go so far as to say that if other classes need an RNG, then it should be move out of this class and into a global `static` one if possible. (It's possible performance requirements may override this advice, but in general, the fewer instances of RNGs you have and the more they're shared, the better.)

Whether the method you're writing needs to be an instance that can be injected will depend on your requirements and the code base surrounding it. I don't see any particular harm in doing so, and I don't have enough context to know whether there's any benefit. The password generator I will present can be trivially converted into a stateless instance that could be injected, though.

## Combining everything

First let's put our randomizing utilities in a separate class:

```
public static class SecureRandom
{
    // We should only ever have one instance of this.
    // Other classes can use this freely, or methods can be added here.
    public static readonly RNGCryptoServiceProvider SecureRNG = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();

    // NextDouble and Next based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/16907577

    public static double NextDouble(this RNGCryptoServiceProvider secureRNG)
    {
        var data = new byte[sizeof(uint)];
        secureRNG.GetBytes(data);
        var randUint = BitConverter.ToUInt32(data, 0);
        return randUint / (uint.MaxValue + 1.0);
    }

    public static int Next(this RNGCryptoServiceProvider secureRNG, int minValue, int maxValue)
    {
        if (minValue > maxValue)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        }

        return minValue + (int)((maxValue - minValue) * secureRNG.NextDouble());
    }

    public static int Next(this RNGCryptoServiceProvider secureRNG, int maxValue)
    {
        return secureRNG.Next(0, maxValue);
    }

    private static T SelectElement<T>(this RNGCryptoServiceProvider secureRNG, IList<T> choices)
    {
        return choices[SecureRNG.Next(choices.Count)];
    }

    // Based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/1262619
    private static void ToRandomOrder<T>(this RNGCryptoServiceProvider secureRNG, IEnumerable<T> sequence)
    {
        var workingList = new List<T>(sequence);

        int n = workingList.Count;
        while (n > 1)
        {
            byte[] box = new byte[1];
            do SecureRNG.GetBytes(box);
            while (!(box[0] < n * (Byte.MaxValue / n)));
            int k = (box[0] % n);
            n--;
            T value = workingList[k];
            workingList[k] = workingList[n];
            workingList[n] = value;
        }

        return workingList;
    }
}
```

With our extension methods above, now we can write the full method:

```
using static SecureRandom;

public static class SimplePasswordGenerator
{
    public static readonly ReadOnlyCollection<char> AllowedLower = ReadOnlyCollection<char>("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");
    public static readonly ReadOnlyCollection<char> AllowedUpper = new ReadOnlyCollection<char>(AllowedLower.Select(x => char.ToUpper(x)));
    public static readonly ReadOnlyCollection<char> AllowedDigits = new ReadOnlyCollection<char>("0123456789");

    public static readonly ReadOnlyCollection<char> PasswordAlphabet = new ReadOnlyCollection<char>(
        AllowedLower
        .Concat(AllowedUpper)
        .Concat(AllowedDigits)
    );

    public static string GenerateSimplePassword(int length = 8)
    {
        if (length < 8)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(paramName: nameof(length), message: "must be at least 8");
        }

        IEnumerable<char> passwordCharacters = new [] { 
            // At least one from each list
            SecureRNG.SelectElement(AllowedLower),
            SecureRNG.SelectElement(AllowedUpper),
            SecureRNG.SelectElement(AllowedDigits)
        }

        passwordCharacters = passwordCharacters.Concat(
            Enumerable.Range(0, length - 3)
            .Select(i => SecureRNG.SelectElement(PasswordAlphabet))
        );

        return String.Join("", SecureRNG.ToRandomOrder(passwordCharacters));
    }
```

Comment: Great point about the biased entropy between digits and letters. And that's the first time I see a _do_ statement written like that.

Comment: @dfhwze Just copy/pasted that `do`/`while` from the other source. lol. When I use other people's code, I try not to change it anymore than I really need to.